# how to restore a collection or collections in mongodb from an archive file?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I have created a dump in an archive file by the following command :

```
mongodump --archive=newcollection.1.archive --db neel --collection newcollection
```

While restoring with the mongorestore i am getting an error :**the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file.**

I got the syntax from [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#examples][1] .

I fired the following command :

```
mongorestore --archive=newcollection.1.archive  --db backup2.
```

Comment: you can't use the --db param when restoring from archive, just use mongorestore --archive=newcollection.1.archive

Comment: then i will get duplicate key error

Comment: And moreover i want to restore data in some specified database

Comment: then you can't use --archive flag. You should do a classic mongodump and work with the BSON files

Comment: You mean to say i can't restore into some other database from archive file?

Comment: as of mongodb 3.4, yes. An issue has been openend for this, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1073

Comment: oh yes that's an issue with mongo 3.4

Answer (score 8):

use --nsFrom and --nsTo

see example :

```
mongodump -h foo.com:27017 --db source_db_name --gzip --archive | mongorestore --drop -vvvvvv -h bar.com:27017 --nsFrom source_db_name.collection_name --nsTo destination_db_name.* --gzip --archive
```

the format for nsFrom and nsTo is database_name.collection_name, and you can use wildcards ( like i did for `destination_db_name.*` ) for the same

[more info](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#change-collections-namespaces-during-restore)

Comment: The example from the docs was giving me the `E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.collection index: _id_ dup key` error. Your answer gave me the hint to remove quotes from `--nsFrom` and `--nsTo`, and the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

```
mongorestore  --archive=<filename>.archive
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to restore a mongodb archived database go to file path and write

```
mongorestore --archive=filename.archive
```

and then press enter it will restore all data of from archive file to your local database.